# XDate vs Datejs

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Has anyone used [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) or [datejs](http://datejs.com)?  Both of them seem to have been out of development for a while, and neither of them have a good release it seems (datejs is "pre-alpha" and xdate is version 0.7).

I'm needing to do some javascript date manipulation (strings -> date objects, date objects -> strings, adding time/days/months to date objects, and calculating the difference in dates).  All of that is possible with the native Javacript Date Object, obviously, but it's so painful - I was hoping someone would have a suggestion on a better API.  These two libraries seem okay, but their age and lack of development history concerns me.

Does anyone have experience with either or both of these libraries?  Or maybe a better alternative that will suit my needs above?

Comment: Another alternative to check out is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: For future readers of this post, please recognize that [Datejs has been abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info), and XDate is [no longer being continued either](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2013/03/xdate-08-and-future-development.html).

Comment: I've been looking for something with Datejs's flexible parsing abilities, and found that [sugar-dates](https://sugarjs.com/dates/) looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used DateJS, but found issues with parsing dates at midnight. I don't recall the details (about 18 months ago), but as the version used on their homepage was not the same as the latest "released" (alpha) version, I tried both. Each had different problems. This was all around parsing, I haven't seen any issues with formatting or manipulation. It was great for that.

Take a look at [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), which is more recent and seems to be actively and rigorously maintained (a pull request was merged in just two days ago as of this writing, for instance, and there are thousands of automated tests).

Comment: Moment JS looks really good, I'm going to check it out a little more!

Comment: MomentJS seems to do everything I want. Two things it could do much better are supporting timezones (currently only UTC or user-local), and "better" formatting syntax. The latter is mostly subjective; IMHO PHP has amazing date formatting syntax, and everything should mimmic that model, but so long as whatever I'm using works and is documented - I'm content. (I just wanted to point out these things in case someone else comes across this info in their own js date lib search, so they'd have a clearer picture of how moment stacks up). PS. thanks for the recommendation for moment, T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

XDate is great; I prefer it to moment because it's API is mostly similar to the native Date object and it works interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post, I found out about moment.js .... actively supported currently which is big plus .. Awesome !!!

both XDate and Date.js are not actively in development now .. Date.js is pretty old library.. (2007 or 2008) ... and same with XDate